# How to create popup window to display contents of text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have C# desktop application I'm converting to C# ASP.Net. It has some functions that output to text files. I already have a C# ASP.Net Default form that performs some functions with buttons and text boxes for output. I want to add more buttons for more functions and simply display the text file generated output from those functions in a popup window (I thought that would be easiest, since I have the desktop code that already does this). What's the best way to create and display popup windows for my text files, using buttons on my Default form? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an Action method that will return the content of your file:

```
    public ContentResult FileContent()
    {
        var data = string.Empty;
        var path = @"c:\temp\output.txt";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        }

        return Content(data);
    }
```

then use jQuery to alert the result from your Action method:

```
<script>
$("#idOfYourButton").click(function () {

    $.get("FileContent", function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx create a popup like this:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pseudopopup" runat="server" visible="false">
    // add button to close this panel 
     <table style="position: fixed; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px"   border="0"  width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"  align="center"  >
    <div style="width:yourwidth; margin-top:60px" class="myshadow" >  
// if file contents are large give a height and make div scrollable
// create css to provide shadow 
    <% 
   Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=windows-1252"; //use if html file
   Response.WriteFile(mfile, true);  %>
    </div>
    </td>            
        </tr>
        </table>    
     </asp:Panel>
```

In code behind

```
   public static string mfile = ""
    protected void btn_click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mfile = "~/yourfile.txt";               
            pseudopopup.Visible = true;

        }
```